# how can we call JDBC code function from another application?

Tags: java, jdbc

how can we call JDBC code function from another application?
so that we don't need to write JDBC code again and again

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in the classpath (if necessary in flavor of a distributed JAR file) and `import` it.

This problem is not specifically related to JDBC, but just to Java in general. To reuse code, all you need to do is to have it in classpath and import the appropriate class and call the appropriate method.

Comment: i have created class consisting JDBC conection code with one method.
when i call that method from another application then
st.executeUpdate() is not valid in NetBeans6.9

Comment: Relax. I was in midst of sleeping. As to your problem: you need to provide more details about the error message.